# Script Not Working over https

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This code works fine in the development machine and over http
but when I change to https stops working
Any help will be greatly appreciated

The code is from zippopotamus is use to get the city and state displayed in their respective input fields by first inserting the zipcode in its input field
here I have a 2 div's that are hidden 
citybox
statebox

when you insert the correct zip these boxes will show with the citybox and statebox

Edit 
The working code its now displayed here Thanks to all here and the suggestion provided by Anders Changing from http to https

```
$(document).ready( function()  {

  $("#citybox").hide();
  $("#statebox").hide();


  $('input#zip').bind("change keyup input",function() {
    var zip_in = $(this);
    var zip_box = $('#zipbox');

    if (zip_in.val().length<5)
    {

      zip_box.removeClass('has-error has-success');
    }
    else if ( zip_in.val().length>5)
    {

      zip_box.addClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
    }

    else if ((zip_in.val().length == 5) ) 
    {

      var urls =["https://api.zippopotam.us/us/" ,"https://api.zippopotam.us/pr/","https://api.zippopotam.us/vi/"];

      $.each(urls, function(i,u){ 
        $.ajax(u + zip_in.val(),{
          cache: false,
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'GET',
          success: function(result, success) {
            // Make the city and state boxes visible

            $('#citybox').slideDown();
            $('#statebox').slideDown();

            // US Zip Code Records Officially Map to only 1 Primary Location for  abbreviation
            places = result['places'][0];
            $('#city').val(places['place name']);
            $('#state').val(places['state']);
            zip_box.addClass('has-success').removeClass('has-error');
          },
          error: function(result, success) {
            zip_box.removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');

          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: you can't load http resources from an https page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zippopotam.us supports https for it's api. Change the urls to "https://api.zippopotam.us/" and it should work.

Comment: Thanks Anders and everyone else  I did change to https

Comment: Sorry I pressed the enter key

Comment: did it again, I did change to https still not showing the results expected and now the hidden div's are always visible, I will read what fred suggested (Same origin policy, but if anyone has other suggestions I will welcome them, Again Thank you All

Comment: Thanks Anders, after looking at my code I accidentally had change some other part of the code, Thanks to you and everyone else here I got it working

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you're reaching an insecure resource (http://api.zippopotam.us/us/) from a secure environment (your site running on https). This is not allowed. Your options are:

- check if this server also runs on https;
- write some back-end code to invoke this service, working like a proxy;
- change to a vendor that supports https.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

You can't make a request to another domain via `HTTP` if your site is running under `HTTPS`.

Thus you should use API via HTTPS or as @Jodevan said use your server as a proxy.

Comment: Thanks Fred I found while reading that I can also use XMLHttpRequest , but I had a mistake in my code just fix it, Thanks again